# Reason for ''Invalid type signature error'' unclear to me

Tags: haskell

I defined the data types below:

```
  data Plan a = Empty | Road a a (Plan a) deriving(Eq, Show)
  data Town a = Emptytown | Town a  deriving(Eq, Show)
  town2 :: Town (Int, String)
  town2 = Town(1, "H")
  town3 :: Town (Int, String)
  town3 = Town(2, "S")
```

But I don't understand why I get the following error when I try to define `Plan2`:

```
  Plan2 :: Plan Town (Int, String)
  Plan2 = Road town2 town3 (Empty)``
  
  <interactive>:456:1: error:
  Invalid type signature: Plan2 :: ...
  Should be of form <variable> :: <type>
```

Comment: You shouldnt use a capital P for Plan2, since that marks it as a data constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- Variable names must start with a lower case letter, but `Plan2` starts with an uppercase letter
- In the type signature for `plan2` you are providing `Plan` with two type arguments but it expects just one. What I think you mean to do is provide `Town` with one type argument and then provide that as the type argument to `Plan`

  ```
  plan2 :: Plan (Town (Int, String))
  ```
- There are two backticks at the end of the definition for `Plan2`. these should be removed.